# Run a command on all the .pst files of a folder in Cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, automation, pst

I have several .pst mailbox in a folder. I would like to use readpst to extract them and have the .msg they contain in a folder.

So let's say 1.pst, 2.pst ... 15.pst. (the actual names are actually a bit longer and more complicated)

I will run a command such as readpst -S -o out/ 1.pst

If I were to run this command in one go for all the .pst files in that folder. How should I amend the command for this to happen? Maybe, put the name of the folder in question? Is there a command that encompass all the document in one folder?

I could make a script of the command I would like to execute and run it for each file, but it won't run on all the file in the folder, right?

Thank you

Comment: Try with for loop: https://ss64.com/bash/for.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems complicated. A friend suggested to put this: readpst -D -S -o msg/ *.pst so all the .pst files in the directory will be taken. Unfortunately it does work with the first one, but not the rest.... :/

Comment: Using the loop with this: $ for thisfile in *; do readpst -D -S -o out/ "$thisfile"; done It worked wonder. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer to my question.

By using the loop with this:

```
for thisfile in *; do
    readpst -D -S -o out/ "$thisfile"
done
```

As suggested by @Biswapriyo using this info: https://ss64.com/bash/for.html